# Correct way of Renting and Returning a multi-dimensional array in C# from shared ArrayPool?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, .net-core, multidimensional-array

For example, is this the correct usage scenario?

```
// Rent
var rentedArray = ArrayPool<int[]>.Shared.Rent(2);

rentedArray[0] = ArrayPool<int>.Shared.Rent(10);
rentedArray[1] = ArrayPool<int>.Shared.Rent(10);

// Return
foreach (var array in rentedArray)
{
    ArrayPool<int>.Shared.Return(array, true);
}

ArrayPool<int[]>.Shared.Return(rentedArray, true);
```

Comment: @Dalorzo sorry i didn't quite understand what you're asking? in general, is this how renting and returning a multi-dimensional array from the shared ArrayPool is done?

Comment: Have you read the [field manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=netstandard-2.1)?

Comment: @NicholasHunter yes I have, I just want to make sure that this is the correct way in renting a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Your code is correct as far as how to use the API to rent and return arrays is being used.

Comment: @mm8 that's what I wanted to know, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct as far as how to use the API to rent and return arrays is being used.

You rent an array with a minimum specified length using the `Rent` API, store it in a variable and then returning that very same array using the `Return` API.

Comment: I'm a bit confused but, wouldn't returning the jagged array also return the other arrays? And if I may ask for a specific use-case: Imagine you have to fill data in a single array 10 times - would you rent and return the array 10 times, or would you rent it once, and clean it up afterwards for every other of the 9 times? Thank you mm8.

Comment: No, you only rent and return a specific instance. Rent, use, clean, return.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify terminology, this would commonly be called a "jagged array" or array-of-arrays.

Eg:

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[2][];
jaggedArray[0] = new int[10];
jaggedArray[1] = new int[10];
```

Contrast with "multi-dimensional array" as it's commonly known:

```
int[,] dimensionalArray = new int[2,10];
```

It appears the ArrayPool class only deals in single-dimensional arrays, so your jagged-array approach is probably what you want.

The code is going to be less than clear.. give some thought to whether that outer-array buffer is really necessary, for your scenario.. and, if so, how to name it in a way that is readably distinct from the inner-array buffers.